# From phone number is not valid SMS capable inbound phone number

Tags: android, authentication, sms, twilio, auth0

I am trying to use my Auth0 custom UI in android to login with phone number using AuthenticationAPIClient. I get this error when I call authAPIClient.passwordlessWithSMS:

The From phone number +441792720641 is not a valid, SMS-capable inbound phone number or short code for your account. (Code: 21606)

Looks like this is a Twilio error, I have checked in twilio console this UK number has voice and sms enabled, and I got this number as part of trial.

How can I get past this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

UK landline numbers, such as the one you have, cannot receive messages from international numbers. If you want to use a UK number, then I recommend getting a UK mobile number. They can send and receive SMS internationally, but cannot make voice calls (which shouldn't be a problem if you are using it for SMS login).

If this is a trial, then the number can also only send to numbers that you have verified in your account.

Does that help at all?

Comment: How can I get a mobile number from Twilio? The number I have got, twilio console says it is voice and sms enabled!  (says on console, so it should be fine) This is still trial account, I am sending message to my verified phone number.

Comment: Are you sending to a non UK number then? I only suggest a mobile number if you are looking for a UK number. Other numbers, like US numbers, can send international SMS, just not UK landline numbers. You can [buy new numbers in your Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/search). Be aware of the footnotes for the numbers though.